# How to make windows .exe executables in Linux [No Duplicate- Extended Version]

Tags: linux, windows, java, wine, cross-platform

Let me describe what I want to do. I want to make a software/application that I can run on both Linux and Windows. It could be any language for example: cpp,java,python.I need to know what is the safest way to make something that I can compile(Cross-compile) into exe in Linux.

I have an idea that you have heard this questions millions of time before. But I have some suggestions to take from you people.

Most of people will tell me to go for wine. I've tried that. But I have heard that windows viruses can affect Linux system through wine. So I feel a bit uncomfortable with it.

Could you please tell me a way that I can make exe files from windows in Linux?

Comment: For me the best way is to use scripting language like python, perl, bash.

Comment: https://justine.lol/cosmo3/ I've no idea how usable/reliable this is, but in theory, this would run on a whole bunch of different platforms on one binary

Comment: It is much better to generate native executables for linux and windows, than to create one executable that works using emulation in one of the two. Especially if you want to use it on multiple systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're writing in C or C++, you can use MingW64 to compile programs for Windows. (It's pretty much gcc, but supports MSVC syntax extensions and outputs an .exe file.) Several projects that people know as Windows apps are actually built using MinGW64 on Linux, often using Qt for the graphical interface.

I *think* the Zig compiler may also be able to do the same (it accepts C).

You probably don't need to do anything special for Java, as Java apps don't run on an OS directly, they run on the Java Runtime (JRE) and there's a JRE for both Windows and Linux – it doesn't matter which OS you compile it on, the .jar is the same either way.

Similarly, the .NET runtime is available on Linux (although WinForms can't run on Linux – but I've seen programs written using gtk-sharp run on Windows).

---

Most Windows viruses will have no way to *enter* a Linux system that's running Wine: it has none of the typical Windows network services (e.g. even if you do have Samba it will be unaffected by the huge majority of Windows SMB.sys vulnerabilities simply because it's a different program); it doesn't have a Windows web browser or a Windows email app; and I assume you aren't planning on double-clicking any random .exe that you find in a USB stick.

Comment: About Java you mentioned. Is it possible to make a .exe file from jar in lnux? If possible how?

Comment: And another thing what is the safe practice with 'wine' to play with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use crossplatform systems like Java(whhich is already crossplatform), Qt (for C/C++) or Xamarin (or other C# crossplatform frameworks). Those can be compiled on both Linux/Windows for any of them.
You can also use just clang/gcc in both systems, and change only system-required varibles or use crosspltaform libraries (dearimgui for GIU creation, for example)